# View value of password edittext while a button is pressed

Tags: android

How can I view the value of an edittext view whose input type is "password" when i click a button and when i release the button, the text display goes back to unreadable format? Like what microsoft does in windows 8 when you click the "eye" that is next to a password field.

Thanks

Comment: doesn't matter what input type it is. just use `edittext.getText().toString();`

Comment: What i meant was, i want to display it on the edittext view

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
 yourButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

               switch ( event.getAction() ) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                   editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                break;
                }
                return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok. I'm able to see the text when I touch the button but when I release it, the text does not transform back to dots (unreadable characters). I placed a Log in the two cases and both cases are being executed correctly.

Comment: Try to put your finger on the "eye" button and then move it in other place and release tap. Password will be shown.

Answer (score 67):

I found one of best solution for **Design Support Library Users:**

It is really easy to achieve with the newest Support Library v24.2.0.

What you need to do is just:

1. Add the design library to your dependencies

   ```
   dependencies {
        compile "com.android.support:design:24.2.0"
   }
   ```
2. Use `TextInputEditText` in conjunction with `TextInputLayout`

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
       android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_spacing_bottom">

       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
           android:id="@+id/etPassword"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:hint="@string/fragment_login_password_hint"
           android:inputType="textPassword"/>
   </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
   ```

The `passwordToggleEnabled` attribute will do the job!

3. In your root layout don't forget to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
4. You can customize your password toggle by using:

`app:passwordToggleDrawable` - Drawable to use as the password input visibility toggle icon.
`app:passwordToggleTint` - Icon to use for the password input visibility toggle.
`app:passwordToggleTintMode` - Blending mode used to apply the background tint.

More details in [TextInputLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I like the current answers! Just to complement, if you have a `CheckBox` it is (according to me) good practice to use its `OnCheckedListener` instead like below:

```
CheckBox box = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.dialog_checkBox_showPassword);
EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialog_editText_password);
box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {

            if(checked){
                password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
            }
            else{
                password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

On pressed button, set `passwordField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);`. When release the button, set `passwordField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
dependencies {implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'}


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_register_password_confirm"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```